# Making a heatmap of similar rows based on categorical values

Tags: r, plot, social-networking, heatmap, correlation

In this simple example, I'm trying to see the number of students sharing the same class. This is what I came up with but I'd like to know how to do this without loops, and potentially how to show which students (or positions P1, P2, P3, P4) share a class together. If these were numbers I think it would be done simply through a correlation matrix, but given the categorical nature I'm not sure how to go about it other than this.

```
DF <- (data.frame(row.names= c("ClassA", "ClassB","ClassC","ClassD","ClassE","ClassF"),
                 P1=c("John","John","Dave","Patrick","Steve","John"),
                 P2=c("Jim","Jim","Robert","Matt","Jim","Ben"),
                 P3=c("Marty","Mike","Stu","Geoff","Mike","Leif"),
                 P4=c("Mark","Mark","Tim","Moby","Chester","Larry")))


DFtally <- matrix(ncol=6, nrow=6)
for (i in 1:dim(DF)[1]) {
  for (j in 1:dim(DF)[1]) {
    DFtally[i,j] <- length(intersect(t(DF[i,]),t(DF[j,])))
  }
}

library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(z = DFtally, type = "heatmap")
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DF2 <- split(as.matrix(DF), 1:nrow(DF))
DF2 <- crossprod(table(stack(DF2)))
DF2

#      ind
#   ind 1 2 3 4 5 6
#     1 4 3 0 0 1 1
#     2 3 4 0 0 2 1
#     3 0 0 4 0 0 0
#     4 0 0 0 4 0 0
#     5 1 2 0 0 4 0
#     6 1 1 0 0 0 4
```